# How to show not found on base url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

This is the code:

App

```
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import ClassroomDashboard from "./ClassroomDashboard";
import Students from "./Students";
import NotFound from "./NotFound";
import Base from "./Base";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Base />}>
          <Route path="dashboard" element={<ClassroomDashboard />} />
          <Route path="students" element={<Students />} />
          <Route index element={<NotFound />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Base

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

function Base() {
  return <Outlet />;
}

export default Base;
```

NotFound

```
function NotFound() {
  return "NotFound";
}

export default NotFound;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-sound-giti8c?file=/src/App.js

I want that when someone goes to the base url say `https://giti8c.csb.app/` then `NotFound` component should be rendered.

Currently, only `Base` component renders on going to the base url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want that when someone goes to the base url say
> `"https://giti8c.csb.app/"` then `NotFound` component should be rendered.

Make an index route that also renders the `NotFound` component, to be matched and rendered only when the path *exactly* matches the parent route rendering the `Outlet` component.

See [Index Routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#index-routes)

Example:

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Base />}>
      <Route index element={<NotFound />} />
      <Route path="dashboard" element={<ClassroomDashboard />} />
      <Route path="students" element={<Students />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```